# partly reindex row indexes Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Need to reindex indexes which are separated by mask and leave unchanged all others indexes

Here is some example:

```
data = {'Name':['Tom', 'nick', 'krish', 'jack'], 
         'Age':[20, 21, 19, 18]} 
pd.DataFrame(data, index =[5,10,15,20])
```

separate by mask rows

```
age_mask = data['Age'] >= 20
```

tried to change indexes for mask rows somehow like here below

```
data[age_mask].index = data[age_mask].index + 1000
```

after execution all indexes stay unchanged.

```
     Name  Age
5     Tom   20
10   nick   21
15  krish   19
20   jack   18
```

and that's what I need to get

```
      Name  Age
1005  Tom    20
1010  nick   21
15    krish  19
20    jack   18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and overwrite index values:

```
data.index = np.where(age_mask, data.index + 1000, data.index)
```

Or use [`Index.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.where.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
data.index = data.index.where(~age_mask, data.index + 1000)
```

---

```
print (data)
     Name  Age
1005    Tom   20
1010   nick   21
15    krish   19
20     jack   18
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
data.index[age_mask] = data[age_mask].index + 1000
print (data)
```

But it return error:

> TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations